# Required classpath for credential detection is missing. Detection is disabled. ERROR in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, server, weblogic

I'm getting this error in Eclipse when trying to create a new Weblogic server.
I've downloaded to types of Weblogic: 14.1.1.0 and 12.2.1.4
Eclipse used: 2023-03

I've modified the JAVA_HOME variable already and don't know what to do now...

[image: Error in ecplise]

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue , what worked for me is I had to go to a lower version of eclipse - 2020_12 to be precise as my code base was in java 1.8 and this issue seemed to come from incorrect java versions(Java_home and eclipse's java version) so when i tried force set eclipse 2023-03 to java 1.8 it didnt support as it requires java 17 or higher.

So went down to 2020_12 installed Oracle server tools and worked fine. it looks like it comes down to compatiblity .